# How do I convert docker-compose configuration to dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am a bit confused I was trying to convert dockercompose of elastic kibana to dockerfile. But networking part and connectivity part is bit confusing for me. Can anyone help me with conversion and a bit of explanation.

Thanks a lot!

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    networks:
      - es-net
    ports:
      - 9200:9200  
  kibana:
    container_name: kb-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.4
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-container:9200
    networks:
      - es-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Dockerfiles and docker-composes serve different purposes, and many things are not translatable to the other. Notably, the networking part cannot be specified in a dockerfile. Also, dockerfiles describe a single container, not multiple (you can do it, but it does not make sense for this purpose).

Answer (score 5):

Docker Compose and Dockerfiles are completely different things. The `Dockerfile` is a configuration file used to create Docker images.  The `docker-compose.yml` file is a configuration file used by Docker Compose to launch Docker containers using Docker images.

To launch the above containers without using Docker Compose you could run:

```
 docker network create es-net
 docker run -d -e xpack.security.enabled=true -e "discovery.type=single-node" -p 9200:9200 --network es-net --name es-container docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
 docker run -d -e ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-container:9200 -p 5601:5601 --network es-net --name kb-container docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.4
```

Alternatively, you could run the containers on the hosts network stack (rather than the `es-net` nework). Kibana would then be able to talk to ElasticSearch on localhost:

```
 docker run -d -e xpack.security.enabled=true -e "discovery.type=single-node" --network host --name es-container docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
 docker run -d -e ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://localhost:9200 --network host --name kb-container docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.4
```

*(I haven't actually run these so the commands might need some tweaking).*

Comment: I wanted to convert the above configuration to dockerfile, I understand both are different things. I wanted to have dockerfile so I can create image and application I am using injests only dockerfile.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to launch the applications shown in the `docker-compose.yml` you listed without using the `docker-compose` tool?

Comment: Yes, given that I am having a hardtime understanding the networking component of it. How do I install both kibana and elastic on single image since having network component requires me to have another interface on it, I guess.

Comment: Combining those two applications into a single container would (without looking at their respective Dockerfiles) almost certainly be a big job. Docker containers aren't really designed to run multiple applications in a single container although it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

In that `docker-compose.yml` file, the only thing that could be built into an image at all are the environment variables, and there's not much benefit to hard-coding your deployment configuration like this.  In particular you cannot force the eventual container name or manually specify the eventual networking configuration in an image.

If you're looking for a compact self-contained description of what to run that you can redistribute, the `docker-compose.yml` is it.  Don't try to send around images, or focus on trying to have a single container; instead, distribute the `docker-compose.yml` file as the way to run your application.  I'd consider Compose a standard enough tool that anyone who has Docker already has it and knows how to run `docker-compose up -d`.

```sh
# How to run this application on a different system
# (with Docker and Compose preinstalled):
here$ scp docker-compose.yml there:
here$ ssh there
there$ sudo docker-compose up -d
```